# Syslog-ng and postgresql connection logs

Tags: postgresql, ovh, syslog-ng

I would like to send postgres connection logs to the OVH Logs Data Platform service with syslog-ng.
How should syslog-ng be configured to send these logs?

Currently I have the following configuration in the ldp.conf file:

```
source s_postgres {
        file("/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}_000000.log" flags(no-parse));
}

template t_postgres {
        template("<${LEVEL_NUM}>1 ${ISODATE} ${HOST} ${PROGRAM} ${PID} - [sdid X-OVH-TOKEN=\"<key>\" pid=\"${PID}\" facility=\"${FACILITY}\" priority=\"${PRIORITY}\"]$
        template_escape(no);
}

d_postgres {
        tcp("<log>.logs.ovh.com"
         port(12201)
         tls(ca_dir("/etc/ssl/certs"))
         ts_format("rfc3339") template(t_postgres)
         keep-alive(yes)
         so_keepalive(yes)
         log-fifo-size(30000)
     );
}

log {
        source(s_postgres);
        destination(d_postgres);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to log RFC 5424 syslog logs to Logs Data Platform, you must use the appropriate port. The port for RFC 5424 is 6514. You can find an exemple of the syslog-ng configuration at the following official documentation:

https://docs.ovh.com/fr/logs-data-platform/how-to-log-your-linux/

For your configuration, your are mostly interested in this part of the documentation (for syslog-ng 3.8+, note also the timestamp format).

```
destination ovhPaaSLogs {
    network("<your_cluster>.logs.ovh.com"
        port(6514),
        template(ovhTemplate),
        ts_format("iso"),
        transport("tls"),
        tls(peer-verify("required-trusted") ca_dir("/etc/ssl/certs/")),
        keep-alive(yes),
        so_keepalive(yes),
    );
};
```

The documentation provides also an exemple of a working template, and other guides will give you alternatives.

Don't hesitate do reach directly the OVH team if you need further assistance at:

https://community.ovh.com/c/platform/data-platforms

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using the tcp() destination driver to produce RFC5424 style data. You are constructing the message format manually whereas syslog-ng would be able to do this for you with its builtin syslog() destination driver.

The problem with producing the RFC5424 format manually using the template() option is that your PID and PROGRAM might be empty at that point and in that case your format would become corrupt (since if the field in question is empty, you'd need to use a dash '-' in its place.

When using the builtin syslog() destination() of syslog-ng, you can still add whatever SDATA fields you'd like. You can do this by setting name-value pairs on the syslog-ng side, right after reading the messages from the log file, e.g. something like:

```
source s_postgres {
    file(...whatever...);
    channel {
      rewrite {
        set("<key"> value(".SDATA.sdid.X-OVH-TOKEN"));
        set("$PID" value(".SDATA.sdid.pid"));
        # and so on
      };
    };
};
```

This way the s_postgres source would produce messages that are originally read from the postgres log file and enriched with some structured data fields
that you populate using the set() rewrite rules right after reading the data there. Once these messages are routed to a syslog() destination the SDATA field would be populated properly.

If you insist on using the current template() solution, you could at least use the "expand with default" feature, e.g. instead of using $PROGRAM, use ${PROGRAM:--}, which is pretty similar to how bash allows this syntax to use $PROGRAM if its set or a literal '-' if it is not. The full syntax is:

`${namevaluepair:-default-if-unset}`